# Multiple instances of server control attached programmatically not appearing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

In the code behind of my page I want to attach a label in multiple places. To achieve this and avoid creating mutliple instances of the same label I've tried:

```
        Label lblNone = new Label();
        lblNone.Text = "<br/> None. <br/>";

        Master.mainContent.Controls.Add(lblNone);
        Master.mainContent.Controls.Add(lblNone);
        Master.mainContent.Controls.Add(lblNone);
```

For some reason I only see 1 instance of the "None." on my page?

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no option.. you need to create one instance of Label for each control you want to see in the screen.

This is because of the behavior of the `ControlCollection` class.

1. it will not allow multiple adds of the same "reference".
2. When you add a control to one ControlCollection it is automatically removed from the previous so, even if you were adding your label to different ControlCollections it wouldn't work.

PS: By ControlCollection I mean the type of the property `Master.mainContent.Controls`

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to create a method for this as so: -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Add(CreateLiteral("text"));
    this.Controls.Add(CreateLiteral("text"));
    this.Controls.Add(CreateLiteral("text"));
}

private Literal CreateLiteral(string Content)
{
    Literal L = new Literal();
    L.Text = Content;
    return L;
}
```

Thanks,

Phil.